# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext While running gradle clean build

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, junit

I have 2 Test files but whenever I try to run **gradle clean build**,

I getting *java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext*, when i remove the *@AutoConfigureMockMvc*, then i get an error *Could not autowire. No beans of 'MockMvc' type found.*

1st File JobTest

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class JobTest {
   @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private JobService jobService;

    private static final String URI = "/testJob/";

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(applicationContext).build();
    }

    private final UUID jobId = UUID.fromString("d35089c0-8ca8-4a9d-8932-8464e9a0736c");
    
    @Test
    public void testRequestJob() throws Exception {

        //create a request object
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(URI)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.ALL)
                .content("testRequestString");

        when(jobService.neededJob(anyString()).thenReturn(mockJob);

        ResultActions perform = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder);
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(), perform.andReturn().getResponse().getStatus());

        //perform the request and get the response
        perform.andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.data.jobId").exists());

    }
 
}
```

2nd File EmployerTest

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ShiftControllerTest {
   @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private EmployerService employerService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(applicationContext).build();
    }

    private final UUID jobId = UUID.fromString("d35089c0-8ca8-4a9d-8932-8464e9a0736c");

    private static final String URI = "/employer/";

    @Test
    public void testEmployer() throws Exception {

        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(URI + jobId)
                .accept(MediaType.ALL);
        when(employerService.getEmployer(jobId)).thenReturn(mockEmployer);

        ResultActions perform = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder);
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(), perform.andReturn().getResponse().getStatus());
    }
}
```

If I comment one file and then try to run **gradle clean build** it works properly, any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: When i try to run the test class separately it works fine but I’m trying to generate jococo coverage report and for that i need to run gradle clean build which results in error

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you have posted you don't seem to use the `WebApplicationContext` for anything else apart from creating a `MockMvc` object which you have already created anyway by virtue of the `@Autowired` annotation. If you don't need it for anything else try just removing the `WebApplicationContext`. For example:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class JobTest {
    // @Autowired
    // private WebApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private JobService jobService;

    private static final String URI = "/testJob/";

    // @BeforeEach
    // void setup() {
    //     this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(applicationContext).build();
    // }

    private final UUID jobId = UUID.fromString("d35089c0-8ca8-4a9d-8932-8464e9a0736c");
    
    @Test
    public void testRequestJob() throws Exception {

        //create a request object
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(URI)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.ALL)
                .content("testRequestString");

        when(jobService.neededJob(anyString()).thenReturn(mockJob);

        ResultActions perform = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder);
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(), perform.andReturn().getResponse().getStatus());

        //perform the request and get the response
        perform.andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.data.jobId").exists());

    }
 
}
```